# Mac server MDM profile manager enrollment problem

Tags: osx-server, mobile-device-management, profile-manager

I use mac os server to active the Profile Manager and Open Directory.
And I want to enroll our devices to the server

Why My ipad and iphone always get the error:

```
Profile Installation Failed
The SCEP server configuration is not supported!
```

[[image]
If I use the server to enroll

```
Profile installation failed.
Could not be installed due to an unexpected error.
<NSOSStatusErrorDomain:-1096>
```

Could anyone  help me !  Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove the pow app as following steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229773/how-to-uninstall-pow-node-on-mac-osx

```
 curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh
```

Now It works without any problem.